Looking up value in data unusually formatted data table? INDEX array mode but not sure how to do it
I am trying to create a formula to look up a value in the table shown in the screenshot. The inputs are AGE, which is in column A, and then the other input is Interest Rate.
For example, if Age: 42 and Interest Rate: 4.375 then I would like the formula to return 0.235, which is the value next to 4.375 in the table.
There are separate tables for each whole percentage (e.g. 3%, 4%, ..., 18%).
One approach could be to use INDEX in Reference Mode and define each Interest Rate as an area_num, and then use Index Match Match to find the value, and then return the value to the right...?
I am not sure how to do this or if it is even the most efficient way, so I would sincerely appreciate help in how best to accomplish this.
Thank you!
image of table I would like to search
Tried Index Match Match but could only get interest rate within a single Interest Rate portion of the larger table, and I want to get the value next to the Interest Rate and be able to search the whole table.

A formula could be created to solve your problem, but your problem isn't the lack of the right formula, it's the poorly formatted data. Doing what you have requested would have been trivial for a normalized data set, but for your input, it will require high-level gymnastics.

It should be a formula to calculate the value depending on inputs.

You could add a column before col A and put the interest rate in that col, then use index() with a double match() - already examples on here so check them out.

It helps giving an example that shows in the posted data image, but it would help even more to post it as markdown table.which makes it easier to reproduce.

The formula to get the result is:
=INDEX(A:Q,3+Age-18+(INT(InterestRate)-3)*83,16*MOD(InterestRate,1)+3)

Probably, this formula will be resided on a sheet different from the Interest Rates table, so A:Q should be used with sheet's name as depicted below.
Name the appropriate cells for Age and InterestRate.


Age: 62
Interest Rate: 5.25
=INDEX(A:Q,3+62-18+(INT(5.25)-3)83,16MOD(5.25,1)+3)
=INDEX(A:Q,47+((5-3)83),160.25+3)
=INDEX(A:Q,213,7)
=0.396
Works!
Thank you!

This was my final formula
=INDEX('FHA PL Table'!A:Q,3+B11-18+(INT(B16100)-3)83,16MOD(B16100,1)+3)
Had reference tab with table, just as you said, and had to multiply decimal interest rate by 100.
Thank you, again!

=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=AgeInput)*(B:P=RateInput)*IS EVEN(COLUMN(B:P))*C:Q)
I used whole range reference to get the logic. Use actual ranges for better performance.

Alternatively getting the "age row" by matching age and whole percentage:
=LET(
  data, A1:Q32, for_age, T1, for_int, T2,
  age_row, INDEX( data,
    XMATCH(1, (INDEX(data, , 1) = for_age) * (INDEX(data, , 2) = TRUNC(for_int))),),
  INDEX(age_row, XMATCH(for_int, age_row) + 1)
)



Thank you! I have to dig into LET, XMATCH, and TRUNC to understand that method but it sure looks like it works. Thanks again.

You're most welcome. I started using these functions earlier this year and find these very helpful.l
